# What should I do if someone is trying to play 'hard to get'?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, negotiation

What should I do if someone is trying to play 'hard to get'? I mean, if many companies want to offer A a job, how can I increase the possibility that A will choose for my company?

Comment: shouldn't this be tagged negotiation??  also maybe give some more background.. do you really need A to take your offer (as opposed to B or C, ...applicants?)

Comment: @Brandin I added the tag 'negotiation'.

Comment: Could you add some more background so that answers may be a little more targeted?

Comment: Is there a point to trying to hire someone if you won't be able to hold on to them anyway? Don't play the hiring game if you haven't worked out how to hold on to your hires.

Comment: How do you know you aren't just being played?

Comment: @RobbieDee, of course he's being played. That's what happens in these negotiations. The question is about how to play professionally and competently.

Comment: I mean how can they be sure candidate A actually *does*  have other options on the table...

Comment: Aren't you already doing everything you can to make the positions you offer more attractive to everybody? This is what it comes to eventually.

Comment: @RobbieDee:  You don't know if you're being played any more than the candidate knows if he's being played when you tell them there are others being considered for the position.  If A is someone you truly want on your payroll, bring your A game (no play on words intended) to the interview and the negotiating table.  If you don't land him, figure out where you fell short.

Comment: @Blrfl Not always true in my experience - there are various things you can do as a potential employer to see if they're on the level or just bluffing for extras. Also, it isn't that unusual for companies to pay (or give perks) over and above the advertised limits stated in job ads and in the interview. It just requires behind the scenes discussions between various parties. This leads back to the first point: You need to be as sure as you can be that you're not being played before breaking the bank to land the candidate.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're actually the one negotiating, the only thing you can do is find out what this candidate values and see if it's possible to offer that. This will involve listening to the candidate and asking the kind of questions that elicit honest answers. To start with, referring to their approach to the negotiation as "playing" and using terminology from dating is probably not a good strategy. Instead, try saying things like this:

> We know that many companies want to hire you. So do we. In addition to our fantastic location and flexible working hours, what else is important to you as you decide what team to join?

Ideally, you learned in the interview that this is a great candidate, and some of what motivates this candidate - inspiring work, great tools, great colleagues, a chance to present at conferences, particular benefits such as health insurance or pension plans, and of course good old cash money. Your negotiation should offer things you know are worth a lot to this candidate. Ideally these are things everyone in your company gets anyway, and offering them is simply one of your strengths.

It may happen that you have to offer something special to this candidate - an extra week of vacation a year, money for training, travel, and conferences, exemption from weekend on-call duty, or more salary - and should you find yourself facing that, be sure to think about how you will handle things with the rest of your staff when word gets out about what the new hire got. Is this candidate amazing enough to justify a 5% increase for all your existing staff so they don't feel bad the new hire makes more than them?

If you didn't pay attention in the interview and have no idea what this candidate wants, it's probably too late to ask now. I mean you can try, sure, but you should start thinking about how to pitch to your second choice, because that's probably who you'll end up making an offer to.

Answer (score 3):

> if many companies want to offer A a job, how can I increase the
>   possibility that A will choose for my company?

Candidates have a variety of reasons for choosing a position - some of those are under your control, but many are not.

You can increase your offer to the point that it is far better than others. This would include salary, bonus, equity, and other other portions of remuneration under your control.

You can also increase the perks being offered. Vacation time, a preferred parking location, a private office, etc.

You might be able to offer work-from-home privileges that have particular appeal to this candidate.

Other aspects of the position are less likely to be under your control. This would include things like the location of the office, the "likeability" of the person managing this position, the reputation of the company, the industry in which you operate - all of these factors can go into a candidate's decision-making process, but probably cannot be changed readily.

You could make a more personal appeal, by having future co-workers contact the candidate to tell him/her why your company is a great place, and why the new manager would be a great person to work for.

You could also ask the candidate directly "What could we offer that would make you want to join us?"

Ultimately though, you can do your best and still not land the candidate. Many in-demand candidates will play off one suitor against the other to raise their compensation. You won't know ahead of time if you are the desired suitor, or are just part of the game. Best to be prepared to move on to another candidate just in case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a highly desirable prospective employee and you're competing with other employers, you obviously can sweeten -- increase the value of -- your offer. You can offer a hiring bonus, a higher salary, a more prestigious title, more shares in your company, tuition benefits, or other perks.

But those things cost money. They may disrupt your relationships with your present employees as well. And, it's pretty well understood that money is a temporary motivator. If you must sweeten your offer, it's best to do it with a hiring bonus that's payable after six months or a year of successful employment.

A good tactic is to behave very professionally. You may even want to be a little hard-nosed. This is the business equivalent of playing "hard-to-get." You may want to say to her, "look, we really want you working with us, and we need to fill this vacancy to get our work done. Please tell us your decision by Thursday, or we need to offer it to someone else."

Another tactic is to appeal to this person's personal sense of mission. Does she know where she wants to go with her career? What is her passion? Wny did she enter her field of work?  Why is your company a great place for her to achieve her personal goals? If you can make the case that your company and her mission in life are compatible, that is a good way to attract and retain her.

@KateGregory mentioned that if you don't know enough about her to make this case to her, it's probably too late to learn now.

One last piece of advice. If you *don't* succeed in hiring her, I suggest you give her a phone call a few days later to ask her about her decision process. you can say, "we respect your decision. You obviously put a lot of thought into it. I'd like to ask you a bit about it. How did you decide whom to work for?" Then *listen.* Do not argue. Do not try to change her mind. If you do this, you'll learn how better to recruit future candidates. (In sales, this is called a *lost sale interview.*)

Answer (score 1):

The key to landing a competitive candidate is to truly understand her/his motivations and to get a clear picture of what really matters to him/her. It's different for every person. In many cases it's NOT something simple like money. Of course your offer needs to be reasonably competitive, nobody is actively looking for a pay cut. So it could be challenging work in an area they are passionate about, could be a credible growth part to the next step, could be appreciation, visibility, mingling with the executive, could be strong ownership of product or project they personally care about, could be flexibility of location and work times, etc.

So if you carefully daylight the real motivations and trigger point you can assess how your opportunity stacks up against them. In many cases you will find that you need to adjust the original job somewhat to make it a better fit, but that's often not much of a problem. Now you can actually offer the candidate his/her "ideal" job, because you did the work to find out how their ideal job actually looks like.

If you find that the needs and wants of the candidate cannot be easily aligned with your job, walk away. It's simply not a good fit.

Answer (score -4):

If you are competing for employees you need to increase your offer:

1 More money

2 More benefits Such as Extra Holiday

3 Better Equity Participation

Comment: What if I don't have the 'resources'?

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards then you will have to accept that you might need to accept a B candidate and train them

Comment: It isn't all about resources. Some perks are free such as flexible hours, working from home, personal time for training/pet projects etc...

Comment: It isn't always about the money. I'd take a good work life balance over a job that pays a lot but expects me to work 12 hours days.

Comment: @Tyanna true for some edge cases - but in most cases its cold hard cash that rules the day

Comment: @Pepone: It's rarely cash. It's total benefits for the employee. The trick for the employer to use is to find and offer things that are of little cost to the employer and of huge benefit to the employee. And if a company wants me to work 12 hours a day, I'd except the same hourly rate as at another company with 8 hour days.